# How to customize woocommerce add to cart button position

Tags: wordpress, forms, button, woocommerce

i have condition "add to cart button" position is on the wrong position, so i want to change the position of the "add to cart button" below the following table as shown in the picture.

[image]

i think just add "
" but i dont know how to edit or add the custom code, anyone can help me how to do it step by step using theme file editor? whould should file i edit?

thank you